# Can C# generics support Class or Nullable?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

In my current project, i have a `Value<T>` class.

Currently `T` can be anything, but we must support `Null` values, so currently we use it in two forms:
`Value<string>` or `Value<int?>`

Can I in any way create a Value class that would allow me to specify `Value<string>` or `Value<int>`, but where the effect is that Value holds `T` for classes, but holds `T?` for structs?

The goal is to avoid the case where a developer specifies `Value<int>` and we later have problems, because we dont handle Null values properly.

Ie, id like Compiler suport for avoiding errors.

Comment: I don't see a possibility (up to c#8) how this should work. `Nullable<int>` (or `int?`) still is only a value type and not a reference, and there is no generic constraint that says "`T` should be `class` **or** `Nullable<TInner>`".

Comment: So without compiler support, you could throw an exception in the constructor of Value<T>.

Comment: Can you describe what is proper null value handling? Maybe comparing to `default(T)` would be suitable for you?

Comment: We are tring to cover 3 options: 1: I know the value, 2: The value is null, 3: I don't know the value.
Our Value container holds a bool NoValue, and a reference to the Type's value.
Because some parties give us null, we have to use nullable. Ex would be DateTime? when a Date field is reset

Comment: Can you describe the difference between a "null value" and "unknown value"? It almost sounds like a 'maybe monad', but that only handles "value" and "no value", where null would fall into the second category.

Comment: @JonasH We are working on a Master Data setup.
The 3 options are: I know the value, I know the value is blank and I don't know the value.
I don't know the value would be a master data value that isnt stored in my system.
I know the value is blank, is when i blanked the value. Ex i change the EndDate of something to null, to symbolize no end date

Comment: The short answer is no, but actually I mean you can... there are multiple ways to do more or less what you're asking, but you'd have to get somewhat fancy - and it might not be worth the complexity, or might not be exactly what you need. (Would have to know more about how you intend to use it, i.e. what methods and properties are you expecting `Value<T>` to have exactly?)

Comment: For example if all you want to do is to be able to write `int? bar = null; Value<int> foo = bar;` then you can solve it with just an implicit operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I in any way create a `Value` class that would allow me to specify `Value<string>` or `Value<int>`, but where the effect is that Value holds `T` for classes, but holds `T?` for structs?

No, because you cannot have "or" logic in generic type constraints.

To achieve "or" logic in generic type constraints, you would have to create two separate generic classes, each with their own generic type constraint. Note that these two classes could inherit from a shared generic base class which has no type constraint at all.
If that base type is abstract, then you can be sure that consumers must have passed one of the derived classes' type constraint check (assuming no one added some other derived classes)

It would be more appropriate to change your expectation instead of trying to make it the way you currently want to.

> but we must support `null` values

If instead of `null`, you use `default(T)`, then the problem is resolved.

- For class types, `default(MyClass)` effectively resolves to `null`
- For structs, `default(MyStruct)` returns a struct whose properties all contain their default values

`default(MyStruct)` is the common way to use the concept of "nullability" without having to use a literal `null` value.

A usage example:

```
public class Container<T>
{
    private readonly Random _random = new Random();
    public T DoSomething(T input)
    {
        //always returns "nothing"
        return default(T);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public struct MyStruct
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public bool ContainerReturnsNothing<T>(T input)
    {
        var container = new Container<T>();

        var output = container.DoSomething(input);

        return output.Equals(default(T));
    }

    public void TestAClassAndAStruct()
    {
        ContainerReturnsNothing(new MyClass()  {Value = 1}); // true
        ContainerReturnsNothing(new MyStruct() {Value = 1}); // true
    }
}
```

In the `TestAClassAndAStruct` method you can see that this generic call stack works exactly the same regardless of whether you use a class or a struct.

If you change the container to `return input`; then `ContainerReturnsNothing` will return `false` in both cases.

---

One thing you may need to be aware of is that a "nothing" struct cannot be differentiated from a struct that was created but whose properties all happen to have default values. If a struct whose properties all happen to have default values, is a meaningful (i.e. not-nothing) struct value in your case, then this is an issue.

A simple example here is `int`, whose `default(int)` resolves to `0`. If `0` is a meaningful value, then it is therefore *not nothing*, which means that you cannot use `0` to represent nothingness.

But you can work around that issue by adding a property which is forced to contain a non-default value when a constructor is executed:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public bool IsConstructed { get; } // default false
    public int Value { get; }

    public MyStruct(int myValue)
    {
        this.IsConstructed = true;
        this.Value = myValue;
    }
}
```

- `default(MyStruct)` will always have `IsConstructed` set to `false`.
- Every instantiated struct will always have `IsConstructed` set to `true`.

This avoid the issue since they will never be equal to one another. In other words:

```
var myStruct = new MyStruct(0);

var isNull = myStruct.Equals(default(MyStruct));
```

`isNull` is false because `myStruct` and `default(MyStruct)` contain a different value for `IsConstructed` (`true` and `false`, respectively).

If you run this same check using the `MyStruct` class from the original example, `isNull` would be true because all the properties match, i.e. `myStruct` and `default(MyStruct)` both have a `Value` property set to `0`.

Comment: @Flater Thanks for the large reply, but unfortunately it doesnt solve my problem.
We are actually using something similar to your suggestion elsewhere in our project.

Comment: @JesperGJensen: I'm not quite qure how that proposed solution invalidates the initial conclusion that you cannot have "or" logic in a generic type constraint.

Comment: I agree that your initial conclusion that im looking for "or" logic in generic type constraints is correct.
The current solution is "don't write wrong code" but keeps the code relatively simple.
Implementing your solution would increase complexity by quite a lot imo, and I think its not worth it.
Althou i agree that technically, your way would allow compiler support for null or default(T)

Comment: @JesperGJensen: Trying to handle two different types as a single type is going to cause more complexity than not writing one additional class definition is going to solve. Hands down, you're going to end up wasting more effort and bugs on typechecking than you will on using two result types.

Comment: Which is also why we currently are sticking to the "don't write wrong code" approach.
I would have preferred to get compiler support here, but we can live without